# Google Script to Duplicate Sheet that is Not Active

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google spreadsheets, i would like to perform a simple copy/rename of an existing spreadsheet in a workbook using a script.  All the examples i have found online are copying from the active spreadsheet.  Can you not perform the below task without first activating/selecting the spreadsheet i want to duplicate?

Example:
My workbook contains the following sheet names:  "Orange", "Blue"

I want to make a copy of "Blue" and rename it to "Red".  So i am left with now 3 sheets "Orange", "Blue", "Red" all while keeping my active spreadsheet on "Orange".

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You have to make "Blue" active, copy it than activate "Orange" back.

Comment: Do you need to make a "deep copy" or would a value/color copy be sufficient ? In the second case you can achieve it using a getValues/setValues (and equivalent for color, BGcolor etc) schema.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) method to copy a sheet into the same spreadsheet, it creates a copy!

```
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Blue');

 sheet.copyTo(source).setName('Red');
```

Comment: thanks really useful :) was looking for duplicate and stuff

Comment: You could also use the [insertSheet method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex,-options) and use a template sheet as a copy template :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Look at sheet's getSheetByName.
If for some reason the api does need the sheet copied to be active (doubt it), simply call setActiveSheet on it before,
.