# Google Apps Script extract specific columns from sheet and put into new sheet using filter & map -- slow

Tags: google-apps-script

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm new to apps script.

I have a gsheet with 98 columns and 25000 rows. All I want to do is copy 24 of the 98 columns to a new sheet.

Currently I am using filter & map, and it works:

var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();  //read all columns & rows into array

var filterData = data.filter(function(e, j){return j > 0 && e}).map(function(e){return [e[88], e[14], e[13], e[4], e[17], e[87], e[91], e[48], e[57], e[31], e[89], e[82], e[70], e[97], e[47], e[30], e[72], e[71], e[67], e[34], e[33], e[00], e[38], e[39]]});  //extract just the columns I want into a new array

but that 2nd line takes almost an hour to execute! I presume because it is processing every element 1-by-1, even though it is just to return each one.

I haven't tried getValue'ing and setValue'ing columns one at a time because everything I read says limit external calls and do everything in memory. And I can't imagine pushing elements 1-by-1 would be faster than filtering.

Suggestions for faster execution?

Answer (score 1):

```
function doCopy(SpreadID, OrgSheet, DestSheet, OrgRange, Sql, DestCell) { 
  var mySpread = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadID);
  var myQry = '=QUERY(' + OrgSheet + "!" + OrgRange + ',\"'+ Sql + '\")';
  var myDestSheet = mySpread.getSheetByName(DestSheet);
  myDestSheet.getRange(DestCell).setFormula(myQry);
}
```

Sample to call, but the destination sheet must be blank:

```
doCopy(spreadsheetId,"Sheet1", "Sheet2", "A:G", "Select A, C, F", "A1");
```

Comment: Thanks user11982798 -- I will try this shortly!

Comment: Perfect solution! You've opened my eyes to the idea of having formulas do more of the work and doing less work in the script. MANY, MANY THANKS!

Comment: And try to use order by, group by, where, calculation and others to the query, for example: "Select A, C, F where A='test' order by C,F". I haven't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the problem which might be more time-effective and easy to implement is the following :

1. Duplicate the original sheet into a new one with `copyTo(spreadsheet)` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet). You might also want to check this post for more information about creating a sheet into the same spreadsheet ([Google Script to Duplicate Sheet that is Not Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533344/google-script-to-duplicate-sheet-that-is-not-active))
2. Delete the columns you don't want to keep with `deleteColumn(columnPosition)` or `deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)`(see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumncolumnposition). 
   You might also want to start deleting columns from the right side of the sheet to make the implementation easier.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: please try to use query

Comment: Thanks David_cav. I neglected to point out that I need the 24 columns in a different order than the original 98 column sheet has them.

Comment: indeed, sorry DemoMan. I didn't get it at first.
I have just tried the solution proposed by user11982798 and it works fine on a small set of data. I assume it should work fine for your use case as well.
Good luck !